# Autologout a user after specific time in django

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-middleware

I need to logout a user after some specific time(lets take it as 1 min for now), and so created a middleware class as below

**myproject/middleware.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib import auth


class AutoLogout:
  def process_request(self, request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated() :
      #Can't log out if not logged in
      return

    try:
      if datetime.now() - request.session['last_touch'] > timedelta( 0, settings.AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY * 60, 0):
        auth.logout(request)
        del request.session['last_touch']
        return
    except KeyError:
      pass

    request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.HttpErrorHandler',
    'myproject.middleware.AutoLogout'
)
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY = 1
```

Djagno version was `1.4.12`

But the above code was not working and i am not sure where i was doing wrong, so can someone let me know why the above code was not working and how to logout a user for every 1 min or 5 min ?

Comment: Are you getting any exception in 'try' block ?

Comment: Can you put in some logging to see whether you get to the try, inside the if, etc.

Comment: actually it was not entering in to process_request method it seems, because i have used some print statements but couldn't able to see then on terminal output

Comment: @DanielRoseman It was not even entering in to process_request method

Comment: maybe you should use jquery ajax which will send GET or POST request  which will run some view in specific time, which will logout user..

Answer (score 12):

From Django 1.7 [Session management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#sessions) was introduced. Under settings there are two parameters that you can add to help you allow auto logout without necessarily writing you own middleware.

1. [SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-expire-at-browser-close)
2. [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age)

Hope that answers your query. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

These answers are all good, but a little out of date and slightly incomplete as of 2023 and Django 4.2, so I've provided some clarifications and colour below for two different common use-cases:

1. Auto log-out after X amount of time **since log-in**
2. Auto log-out after X amount of time of **inactivity**

---

**Use-Case 1: To log-out users automatically after 'X' amount of time has elapsed *since they last logged-in***

*SIMPLE APPROACH (appropriate for most projects):*

Inside *settings.py*, set **`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = X`**, where 'X' is the amount of time to elapse since last log-in in terms of seconds, and **`SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False`**.

For example, the below code in *settings.py* will log users out after 5 days have elapsed since their last log-in:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60  # 5 days
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False  # Only save session when session modified
```

- CAVEAT: This simplified approach will work provided your views and middleware other than log-in/log-out **do not modify the `request.session` object**. This approach will **fail** in its aim if you modify the session object, as doing so will update and reset the session cookie's age.

*COMPLEX APPROACH (appropriate for projects that modify sessions in non-auth views, or which have bespoke requirements):*

If your views or middleware do change the session object, or if you want fine-grained control over this (e.g. different settings for different users), you will need to use custom middleware.

The below code is not thoroughly tested, and is dependent on your user model implementing a `last_login` field (Django includes this by default for User, AbstractUser and AbstractBaseUser). But as an example your middleware should look something like this inside *myapp/middleware.py*:

```py
class AutoLogoutMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if timezone.now() - request.user.last_login > timedelta(days=5):
                logout(request)  # Logout if 5 or more days since last login
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

And you would then import your middleware into *settings.py* as below (ensuring it comes AFTER sessions and auth middleware):

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ... possibly earlier middleware ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # ... possibly other middleware ...
    'myapp.middleware.AutoLogoutMiddleware',
    # ... possibly further middleware ...
]
```

---

**Use-Case 2: To log-out users automatically after 'X' amount of time has elapsed *since they were last active***

This can be achieved easily as follows:

Inside *settings.py*, set **`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = X`**, where 'X' is the amount of time to elapse since last activity in terms of seconds, and **`SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True`**.

For example, the below code in *settings.py* will log users out after 30 minutes of inactivity.

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 30 * 60  # 30 minutes
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True  # Refresh session whenever user is active
```

Note you can also achieve a similar effect with custom middleware, if you have more bespoke requirements, but this may be more complex than needed.

- CAVEAT 1: Note that setting **`SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True`** will increase the number of hits to your database by 1 for each request, as each request will now be updating the session. Ensure you can cope with this additional database load.
- CAVEAT 2: Be very careful about setting too low a value for `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`, e.g. in a situation where you have a large form. If the user takes longer than 'X' amount of time filling in your form, then on submit they will be logged out and redirected to the log-in page, and all their form data will be lost (potentially very bad UX, typical of many a poorly designed site).

---

**P.S.** the inclusion of **`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE`** is also a powerful session-based security measure for many use-cases. All Django session settings can be seen in the official docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#sessions).